# How to automate a git-flow with Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-flow

How to create jobs to control git-flow?

We know that in the git-flow process, we have specific branches to be used and at the right times, such as (develop, hotfix, feature) and we also know that when inserting the source code into main (which would be the last step) , the commit must be versioned.

That is, how to create a job to do this control of push's, following git-flow and also the automated versioning of the code?

EXAMPLE:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're looking for: You want a workflow to trigger on each PUSH event, automatically merging or finishing branches according to the git flow (branches names), and generating semantic version tag automatically once merging into the main branch?

Comment: Yes! Exact! GuiFalourd!

Comment: In that case, you would probably have to use a script, or shell commands, directly on the workflow steps according to each possible scenario. This workflow would be triggered on each push, and performed different operations according to the context in which the branch is. There is no specific action that does what you need today (but it's an opportunity to create something new as well!).